# The const char* should it be freed in C?

Tags: c, function, char, constants, free

Please consider the following code. I am asking if this is correct, is there something missing. Is there any other way to make it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
const char *getOrder (const char *day)
{
    if (strncmp(day, "Monday", 7) == 0) {
        return "first";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Tuesday", 7) == 0) {
        return "second";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Wednesday", 9) == 0) {
        return "third";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Thursday", 8) == 0) {
        return "forth";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Friday", 6) == 0) {
        return "fifth";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Saturday", 8) == 0) {
        return "sixth";
    } else if (strncmp(day, "Sunday", 6) == 0) {
        return "seventh";
    } else
        return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    const char* str = NULL;
    str = getOrder ("Monday");
    printf("str : %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only pass to `free` what was returned from `malloc` and related functions.

Comment: There are no dynamic memory allocations (via `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`), here, so there is nothing to `free`. You only have pointers to string literals being manipulated here, and you can't free those.

Comment: There are nothing to be freed in your code because there are no dynamic memory allocation. How do you define "correct"? For example, what is your expected output for `getOrder("Fridayear!!!!!")`?

Comment: @Zakk Data for string literals will typically allocated on static data area, not on the stack.

Comment: It looks fine to me. But definitely you can over engineer this

Comment: @MikeCAT getOrder("Fridayear!!!!!") couldn't pass in my code,  in my original one I have a condition that  accept only days

Comment: Suggest changing `return NULL;` for no match with `return "No match";`

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com for code review.

Comment: @sanaf What do you mean my engineer this. This what I am looking for. Is there any other way, better, and more professional than this one to manage the returned const char.

Comment: IMO you should use arrays and a loop instead of multiple occurances of `strncmp`.

Comment: Your use of `strncmp` is meaningless. Replace with `strcmp`.

Comment: _"Is there any other way, better, and more professional than this one..."_  See the comment suggesting **code review**. (4 up from this one.) It is a very good site to ask questions such as this, where the code is generally in working order, but programmer want's other's opinion/expertise to improve it.

Comment: @Lara when I say over engineer the code I mean implementing a hash map or something like that. \

Comment: Furthermore, replace the chain of `if...else` statements with a search in an array (binary search preferred). A hash map is probably an overkill.

Comment: @Sanaf Please check out my answer to this OP... Below the LUT code I also posted a working 'hash function' for English weekday names. A few bitwise operations and one has a 'guess' at which day is named. Then, one need only test against that single string, instead of hoping to get lucky. Who wants to wait until after lunch when myriad unknowns are to be quantified?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I see you are a man of culture! +10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if/else ladder is overly complicated and prone to 'copy/paste' errors.

It seems you want a "look up table" to translate a weekday name to a different string.

```
const char *getOrder (const char *day) {
    char *LUT[][2] = {
    { "Monday", "first", },
    { "Tuesday", "second", },
    { "Wednesday", "third", },
    { "Thursday", "forth", },
    { "Friday", "fifth", },
    { "Saturday", "sixth", },
    { "Sunday", "seventh", },
    };
    
    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(LUT)/sizeof(LUT[0]); i++ )
        if( strncmp(day, LUT[i][0], strlen( LUT[i][0] ) ) == 0 )
            return LUT[ i ][ 1 ];

    return "NOT A DAY NAME";
}
```

It's still iteratively hunting...

Here is a tiny hash function to quickly translate string day names to an integer value (case insensitive). Play with it. Perhaps you will try to adapt this to go straight to the plausible weekday name.

```
// Convert a day name (or 3 letter abbrev.) to index (1-7, Sun=1). Beware false positives!
static int wkdayOrd( char cp[] ) { return "65013427"[*cp/2 + ~cp[1] & 0x7] & 0x7; }
```

Comment: `strncmp(day, LUT[i][0], strlen( LUT[i][0] ) )` - why on earth do a `strlen` there instead of just using `strcmp` which includes a check for `\0` ? It just wastes resources without any benefits.

Comment: Because the passed string ('weekday name') may not end with '\0'.

Comment: An how does taking the length of `LUT[i][0]` help to prevent that? If the passed string does not end with `\0` the hope is lost anyway.

Comment: The OP asked for alternatives to their if/else ladder. This alternative still respects the OP use of `strncmp()` (providing a length to check.) Consider, please, that "Mondays" may be as valid a string as "Monday". "Club meets on Mondays" -> "Club meets on the first day of week".

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean. I missed that part! +1

Comment: Is the comma immediately after the second item in each subarray intentional? This isn't Python so I am unsure. Also, what about the last comma in `{ "Sunday", "seventh", },`?

Comment: @Stev The commas you point out are, in this code, superfluous. It's a holdover habit from days of working at code that was constantly evolving. (Eg. deciding to change to an array of structs and including the length of each target rather than using `strlen()` (kinda like the OP's `if/else` did.) ... Answered this question primarily to spread the one line _hashing_ function at the end. Give that a try...

Answer (score 5):

What will determine if you have to free or not is not the type of the variable, but on which part of memory it resides.

If you allocate memory using `malloc` or a related function, it will live on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP), thus you have to call `free` on them.

In your example, these strings are created in [static memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) (not from the stack as suggested in one of the comments, otherwise you could not use it once the function returns, as they would have been overwritten).

These strings are compiled into the run-time binary itself (you can run `strings <your binary>` and you will see them. Once the program is loaded, a special area of the memory is reserved for such constant data, thus you don't need to free it.

As a side note, you have to read the C/C++ types from right-to-left, so
type `const char*` means is that you have a pointer to a constant string. That means that you cannot modify the string pointed by it, but it does not say anything about how the memory behind this pointer was allocated. It could be on the heap, on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable), or on static memory, just the type will not tell you.

Comment: Can you link a reference how to use `strings <your binary>`?  I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @ryyker Just type this on the command line (replace `<your binary>` with the file name of your binary).

Comment: If you're using Linux or any UNIX, just run `man strings` in a terminal to see the documentation. If you're on Windows, you'll need WSL or cygwin or something to get this. It's not important though, it's just indicating that string literals are stored in the executable by the compiler.

Comment: Also, you'd still see those strings in the executable if you wrote `strdup("first")` in your code, and you _would_ need to `free` that. Honestly, worry about the object lifetime before thinking about `strings`

Comment: @Useless - I am on Windows, but do have Cygwin loaded, will give it a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion is NO.

The reason is free() should be used as the partner of malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). Or to say only a pointer is returned by those alloc function, could it be recycled by free().

And an addtional reason is all those strings you write in your code is allocated in section .rodata, that means those strings are loaded in a memory space you cannot edit but only read, so even there is a method to free them, you still cannot util the memory space.